# Prove that language is regular given other regular language

Tags: regular-language

Let $L\subseteq A^*$ be regular. Prove that $L'$ is regular where
$L' = \{vw \mid \exists u\in A^*\ vuw \in L\wedge |u|=|w|+|v|\}$

Help me please. It is very hard for me, I don't know how to start. This type of exercises is extremely hard.

Comment: Start with the definitions. Do you know what it means for a language to be regular? Do you know what the notation $|u|$ means, and what the other notations in the question mean?

Comment: Yes, I know all defintions. I know that I should DFA or regex.

Comment: Good. So, what does it mean for a language to be regular?

Comment: It is recognized by DFA(NFA). Also we may express it with regex.

Comment: Is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247986/proving-by-construction-that-language-is-regular any help?

Comment: Is it? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Ok, it helps me a bit, but I still can't sove it